# If $G$ is a connected topological group, then every connected neighbourhood of $e$ generates $G$.

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, topological-groups

Here's how I proved it:

Let $U$ be a connected neighbourhood of $e$. Then $\langle U \rangle$ is a connected subgroup of $G$ that is both open and closed. Since $G$ is connected, then $\langle U \rangle = G$.

Now, I didn't use the assumption that $U$ is connected. I feel that I must have missed something. Please enlighten me.

Comment: Haven't you used it when you said that $\langle U\rangle$ is a connected subgroup?

Comment: @uniquesolution I feel that $\langle U \rangle$ being connected is irrelevant. It being both open and closed should be enough. Or I'm not even sure if that's the case.

Comment: You claim that $\langle U\rangle$ is both open and closed. How does it follow exactly?

Comment: @freakish I used the fact that for for each $k \in \mathbb{N}$, $x_{1},\dotsc,x_{k} \in U$, and $n_{1},\dotsc,n_{k} \in \mathbb{Z}$, the left translation function $L_{x_{1}^{n_{1}} x_{2}^{n_{2}} \cdots x_{k}^{n_{k}}}$ is a homeomorphism, so that $L_{x_{1}^{n_{1}} x_{2}^{n_{2}} \cdots x_{k}^{n_{k}}}(U)$ is an open set that contains $x_{1}^{n_{1}} x_{2}^{n_{2}} \cdots x_{k}^{n_{k}} = L_{x_{1}^{n_{1}} x_{2}^{n_{2}} \cdots x_{k}^{n_{k}}}(e)$.

Comment: @ShuichiSaihara note that this only shows that $\langle U\rangle$ is open.

Comment: @freakish yes. I forgot. All open subgroups of a topological group is closed. Hence $\langle U \rangle$ is closed too. I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general if $G$ is a topological group and $H\subseteq G$ is a subgroup with nonempty interior, then $H$ is both open and closed. Indeed, if $U\subseteq H$ is open and $u\in U$, then $H=\bigcup_{h\in H}hu^{-1}U$ showing it is open. And this implies that $H^c$ (the set theoretical complement of $H$) is open as well, because $H^c=\bigcup_{g\in H^c}gH$.

And so if $G$ is connected, then given any subset $A\subseteq G$ with nonempty interior we have $\langle A\rangle=G$. Therefore you are correct, connectedness of the subset is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

$\langle U \rangle$ can be written as a union of sets that are continuous images of products of $U$ and that all contain $1$, so standard facts about connectedness (preserved by continuous images, products, linked unions) are needed to show it is connected. So you *do* use it, maybe implicitly.

Comment: Yes, but the proposition that $U$ being connected implies $\langle U \rangle$ is connected is irrelevant to show that $U$ generates $G$.